# validate precision in grails

Tags: grails, groovy

I'm wondering how you validate precision in grails? I see scale, but not precision in the docs.

Example

```
static constraints = {
    percentTime( nullable: true, precision: 5, scale: 4)
}

1.003 works fine.
10 fails with an exception.
```

https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Constraints/Usage.html

Comment: It'd help if you supply an example that validates for the scale but not the precission, to make things clearer.

Comment: @Deigote example provided.